# How to update a Lookup field in one list with info from another list using Powershell or Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, designer-workflow

I have a site that an SSIS package dumps thousands of items on to. The manager of the department wants a second list created. He wants to use a lookup column on list two to grab a single field called "Batch ID" from list one, and have it pull all the other data from list one into list two. He then wants a few columns added to list two that users are supposed to edit.

What I need to do is either use Powershell or a Workflow to grab the "Batch ID" columns from list one, input the info into the Lookup Column "Batch ID" in list two, so list two can use the lookup column to bring all the other info over.

Comment: once the SSIS process finish, schedule a powershell script to go through imported list items with related fields and then push into the second list.